# error: non-aggregate type 'Circle' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Tags: c++

I'm in need of help with an assignment for my C++ class. My problem is trying to compile a program I got from my professor. Every time I try to compile the code I get the following error

> "error: non-aggregate type 'Circle' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
>
> ```
> Circle list[] ={  { 93, "yellow" },
> ```

same error follows for the second circle in the array. Can someone tell me what I need to do to get this code to compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 Circle list[] ={  { 93, "yellow" },
                   { 27, "red"    }
                };

 Circle *p;
 p = list;

 cout<<(*p).getRadius()<<endl;
 cout<<(*p).getColor()<<endl;
 cout<<p->getRadius()<<endl;
 cout<<p->getColor()<<endl;

 p++;

 cout<<(*p).getRadius()<<endl;
 cout<<(*p).getColor()<<endl;
 cout<<p->getRadius()<<endl;
 cout<<p->getColor()<<endl;

 return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=c++11`. If that doesn't fix the problem show us the definition of the `Circle` class. And post what compiler you're using and its version number.

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11? Does your compiler support this feature? On a side note, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of requiring us to make a `Circle` class and including 10x more other code than necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the lack of support of c++11. On the other hand you might as well just change the declaration of your list and call explicitely the constructor

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone.I'm new to all this so I'm trying to research how to compile with -std=c++11.I'm not sure what compiler I'm using but its the default Xcode compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of C++ are you using? Before C++11, any class with at least one constructor could not be constructed using an aggregate list:

```
struct A
{
    std::string s;
    int n;
};
struct B
{
    std::string s;
    int n;

   // default constructor
    B() : s(), n() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a = { "Hi", 3 }; // A is an aggregate class: no constructors were provided for A
    B b; // Fine, this will use the default constructor provided.
    A aa; // fine, this will default construct since the compiler will make a default constructor for any class you don't provide one for.
    B bb = { "Hello", 4 }; // this won't work. B is no longer an aggregate class because a constructor was provided.
    return 0;
}
```

I daresay Circle has a constructor defined, and cannot be constructor with an aggregate initialisation list pre C++11. You could try:

```
Circle list[] = { Circle(93, "Yellow"), Circle(16, "Red") };
```