# I changed my Makefile into C++11 version, but still getting a List Initializer Error

Tags: c++, makefile

I made a Makefile:

```
output: main.o ./source/BlackJack.o ./source/Card.o ./source/Game.o ./source/Image.o
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o ./source/BlackJack.o ./source/Card.o ./source/Game.o ./source/Image.o -o BlackJack

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp

BlackJack.o: ./source/BlackJack.cpp ./source/BlackJack.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c ./source/BlackJack.cpp

Card.o: ./source/Card.cpp ./source/Card.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c ./source/Card.cpp

Image.o: ./source/Image.cpp ./source/Image.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c ./source/Image.cpp
```

But I am still getting an error message of

```
source/Game.cpp:80:20: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<Casino>' cannot be
      initialized with an initializer list
    vector<Casino> casVec = {flamingo, mirage, bellagio};
```

I think I changed compiler's version into c++11.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the = in the initialization statement.

Comment: In the `output` line it includes paths with objects, but in the compilation rules it does not include the path.  So when you request `./source/BlackJack.o`, it does not find the rule `BlackJack.o` and may be falling back to the implicit build rule .  You should be able to confirm this by watching the build output, it should write `g++ ./source/BlackJack.cpp` or something on the console as the implicit rule is invoked

Comment: or try invoking as `make -r`  , this will give an error if it can't find your rule instead of falling back to the builtin.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29908771/9254404 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Makefile does not have an entry for `source/Game.o: source/Game.cpp` so it falls back to the built-in rule:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

...which does not automatically compile as C++11.

You can thus simplify your Makefile significantly by doing

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

and removing all your custom rules for compiling cpp files.

You may also want to invest some time in learning CMake, where you can define your sources, targets and compile options at a higher level.